# Furnace Blower fan doesn't start

Tags: hvac, heating, furnace, heat

I have a keeprite high efficiency furnace that Was a part of my new house. It's 2016.

The Honeywell thermostat is set at 23 deg C. This is what happens when the temperature is below the cut-off

1. I hear the furnace kicking in. No fan is heard
2. The section right above the furnace become hot and suddenly the furnace shuts down. A burning smell is there from the vents in some rooms
3. 4 times LED blinking is seen and after sometime turns to 7 times.
4. I turn off the furnace and wait for 2-3 mins and start it again and everything is fine - blower kicks in after burner is ignited

I had the HVAC technician visit my place but I could not reproduce the issue.

Stuff I have already checked: combustion air flow from the vent is good. All wires and trips are great.

The fault codes are here: http://tradesmandrcool.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/KEEPRITEHighEff.pdf

Edit: I read somewhere that fan set to Auto is for cooling only. Tried to keep the fan ON and ran into the same issue again. However, at night the 7 flashes showed up against me I left the furnace running with fan set to ON. In the morning I observed the fan was running. By the way, there aren't any nests or dust. I checked for that as well

Thanks

Comment: What model is the furnace?

Comment: The burning is presumably, NEW from dust, since the cooling season is over and the heating season is beginning. Be sure to change your air filter. Now is the right time to do it. Make sure the side vent is not clogged. Birds and such like to nest in there. The tech must not be very savvy since he/she could easily override the temp switch temporarily. Also, you might have an issue where the impeller is seizing or failing to startup. My money is on a bird, spider or a tennis ball from a friendly kid. Secondly, the impeller. Of course the motor discussion could apply to the blower... but

Comment: The model is keeprite Gm9xe high efficiency.

Comment: @nobyman: the furnace ran a lot in the past few days so not sure if it's dust. The previous owner also did a duct cleaning before we moved in.

Comment: Furnaces vibrate a lot...it can cause connections and parts to fail.  Check every connection you can find.   Especially sensors.

Comment: Blower not kicking in may mean that the furnace isn't detecting that there is flame (even if it's getting hot).  Are you saying it is blinking "4 blinks"?  How many blinks during #3?

Comment: CODE: 6 + 1 Flashes
RESULT: Soft lockout - Max of 4 trials for ignition reached (3 hour delay).
FIX: Control will auto-reset after 3 hours.
CODE: **7 Flashes**
RESULT: Soft lockout - **Limit of roll-out switch open longer than 2 minutes** (1 hr delay)(rollout switch requires manual reset).
FIX: A lockout will occur if the limit or flame rollout is open for longer than 3 minutes. **Control will auto-reset after 3 hours.**

Comment: Failed to ignite or open limit. But if I had to guess, it's the capacitor on the blower. It knows nothing about that. Only that it got too hot; "limit [or] roll-out switch"? It's never the roll outs IME. It's always the high temp limit; either gone bad, or there's an underlying problem (capacitor).

Comment: https://twintechheating.ca/keeprite-furnace-error-codes/

Answer (score 0):

Get the furnace to show the problem again.  Then don't touch anything.  call for service.  As long as power is not interrupted, the furnace will hold those blink codes in memory. The service man can interpret the code and solve the problem.

Comment: I left it as it is and it was running in the morning. It had the 7 flashes fault code at night and it resets after 3 hours.

Answer (score 0):

There may be a rotation of codes.  They are all saved in the memory for the next serviceman.  Or there may be other conditions affecting the situation.  These are very sophisticated appliances.  It is not wise to try to outsmart them.  You could void the Warrantee. Please consult a pro.